# How to create a SQL database based on parameter being met in another database

Tags: sql

I currently have a large database with a couple hundred thousand rows and I am trying to filter down to meet certain parameter for a new table.

I currently have the code:

```
SELECT sym, tstamp, COUNT(*) AS trades 
FROM datas 
GROUP BY sym, tstamp 
HAVING COUNT(tstamp) > 300
```

Which gives me the filtered table that I am looking for. However I am stuck from here on how to create a new table once I have this result. I'm sure this is fairly straightforward but I have been stuck on it for a couple of hours.

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
"INSERT INTO newdb SELECT * FROM datas 
 WHERE sym, tstamp, COUNT(*) AS trades 
 FROM datas GROUP BY sym, tstamp 
 HAVING COUNT(tstamp) > 300"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just have an extra `SELECT * FROM datas` in there.

```
INSERT INTO tradecounts
SELECT
    sym,
    tstamp,
    COUNT(*) AS trades
FROM
    datas
GROUP BY
    sym,
    tstamp
HAVING COUNT(tstamp) > 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreign key concept in which parent table primary key field will also be matched with the primary key field in child table.This primary key field of child table will be the Foreign key for parent table.

eg...Table1-Department ,Table 2-Employee with depid as primary key of both the table than table would be like -

Create table department (depid varchar(10) primary key,name varchar(50),salary number,constraint xyz foreign key(depid) references department (depid) on delete Cascade)

After on Delete we provide mode like - SET NULL,CASCADE ,SET DEFAULT

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create new the table using this query then you can use `CTAS` (`CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`) as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE NEWDB AS
SELECT sym, tstamp, COUNT(*) AS trades 
FROM datas 
GROUP BY sym, tstamp 
HAVING COUNT(tstamp) > 300
```